# Automatic background change with JavaScript and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have used mixed colors for the background of a page of my site.

Now I want to add new combination colors and change these colors automatically every 5 seconds.
I don't know exactly where to start and I just put the code I used to change the color of the element once again for the background of the page and it didn't work at all.

```js
const Border_Main = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        const Content = entry.target.querySelector('#background');

        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            Content.classList.add('background-body');
            return;
        }
        Content.classList.remove('background-body');
    });
});

Border_Main.observe(document.querySelector('body'));
```

```css
html,body{
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
}

#background{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #39c787;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 15% 0%, 75% 84%, from(#ca83ddc4), to(#7874e3f3), color-stop(70%, #dfa450ab));
    transition: all 5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 5s ease;
}

.background-body{
    background: #e0922d !important;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 15% 0%, 75% 84%, from(#9283ddc4), to(#22ff12d1), color-stop(70%, #c550dfab)) !important;
    transition: all 5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="background">


</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that an `IntersectionObserver` is needed here. Similar to your attempt, here is one example where `background-body` is added or removed every five seconds from the `classList`.

```js
var i = 0;
function changeBackgroundColor() {
  var background = document.getElementById("background");

  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    background.classList.remove("background-body");
  } else {
    background.classList.add("background-body");
  }
  i = i + 1;
}
setInterval(changeBackgroundColor, 5 * 1000);
```

```css
html,body{
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
}

#background{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #39c787;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 15% 0%, 75% 84%, from(#ca83ddc4), to(#7874e3f3), color-stop(70%, #dfa450ab));
  transition: all 5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 5s ease;
}

.background-body{
  background: #e0922d !important;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 15% 0%, 75% 84%, from(#9283ddc4), to(#22ff12d1), color-stop(70%, #c550dfab)) !important;
  transition: all 5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="background"></body>
```

Comment: Hello. `I apologize for my late reply`. Your code is exactly what I want but there is a problem with changing the colors. When another class is added to change the color, this class is added quickly and the color jump is visible. Is it possible to adjust the way the color changes so that it does so **slowly** and without color jumps?

Comment: I accepted your answer and created a new question for this. Please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76903496/automatic-background-change-with-javascript-and-css-part-two

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use `setTimeout()` method in js and set 5000ms for the time then you can change the color every 5 second