# Automatic background change with JavaScript and CSS (part two)

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my previous question and with the help of (Jan), I solved the problem of automatic background change.

My previous question: [Automatic background change with JavaScript and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76891752/automatic-background-change-with-javascript-and-css/76892321?noredirect=1#comment135572299_76892321)

But when the background is changed, the color jump is visible and I want the color change to be done without jump and slowly.

```js
var i = 0;
function changeBackgroundColor() {
  var background = document.getElementById("background");

  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    background.classList.remove("background-body");
  } else {
    background.classList.add("background-body");
  }
  i = i + 1;
}
setInterval(changeBackgroundColor, 3 * 1000);
```

```css
html,body{
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
}

#background{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #39c787;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 15% 0%, 75% 84%, from(#ca83ddc4), to(#7874e3f3), color-stop(70%, #dfa450ab));
  transition: all 5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 5s ease;
}

.background-body{
  background: #e0922d !important;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 15% 0%, 75% 84%, from(#9283ddc4), to(#22ff12d1), color-stop(70%, #c550dfab)) !important;
  transition: all 5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="background"></body>
```

Comment: You can use CSS animation property. Please refer codepen. https://codepen.io/P1N2O/pen/pyBNzX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an absolutely-positioned pseudo-element with a different background, then transition an opacity change on that.

```js
function changeBackgroundColor() {
  document.body.classList.toggle("alt-background")
  setTimeout(changeBackgroundColor, 4000)
}
changeBackgroundColor()
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(131,58,180,1) 0%, rgba(253,29,29,1) 50%, rgba(252,176,69,1) 100%);
}

body::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}

body.alt-background::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```